# Android native global 2D vector element reading causes segmentation fault crash

Tags: android, c++, vector, crash, java-native-interface

I am having segmentation fault from crash reports and the report is only suggesting the error is coming from the following JNI function:

```
jboolean
Java_package_name_ClassName_isCellEmpty(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */, uint8_t row, uint8_t col) {
    return (jboolean)(cells[row][col] == (uint8_t) 0);
}
```

`cells` is a non-static 2D vector declared globally like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t> > cells (3, std::vector<uint8_t>(3));
```

In my java code, `isCellEmpty` function is called anytime later after calling `nativeInit` which makes sure the `cells` 2D vector is initialized like this:

```
Java_package_name_ClassName_nativeInit(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cells[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So, all the vector elements has values confirmed and the crash doesn't occur in many devices including my Nexus 7 (2013) Android version 6.0.1. But I am receiving huge amount of crash reports from many other devices. Any idea about where is it coming from? Should I use `at()` to access vector elements?

Comment: Verifying that `row` and `col` have valid values seems like a good start.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the comment. Actually they have valid values for many devices including Nexus 7 and I also tested on Firebase Test Lab with a Google Pixel device. But many other devices are reporting a crash for this. For example Lava Iris820, but those devices aren't available in Test Lab.